# aggregating and sorting based on a Mongodb Relationship

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out if what I want to do is even possible in Mongodb. I'm open to all sorts of suggestions regarding more appropriate ways to achieve what I need.

Currently, I have 2 collections:

vehicles (Contains vehicle data such as make and model. This data can be highly unstructured, which is why I turned to Mongodb for this)

views (Simply contains an IP, a date/time that the vehicle was viewed and the vehicle_id. There could be thousands of views)

I need to return a list of vehicles that have views between 2 dates. The list should include the number of views. I need to be able to sort by the number of views in addition to any of the usual vehicle fields. So, to be clear, if a vehicle has had 1000 views, but only 500 of those between the given dates, the count should return 500.

I'm pretty sure I could perform this query without any issues in MySQL - however, trying to store the vehicle data in MySQL has been a real headache in the past and it has been great moving to Mongo where I can add new data fields with ease and not worry about the structure of my database.

What do you all think?? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it's totally possible. It took me a long while to get my head around this, so I'm posting it up for future google searches...

```
db.statistics.aggregate({ 
  $match: { 
    branch_id: { $in: [14] } 
  } 
}, { 
  $lookup: { 
    from: 'vehicles', localField: 'vehicle_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'vehicle' 
  } 
}, { 
  $group: { 
    _id: "$vehicle_id", 
    count: { $sum: 1 }, 
    vehicleObject: { $first: "$vehicle" } 
  } 
}, { $unwind: "$vehicleObject" }, {
  $project: {
    daysInStock: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$vehicleObject.date_assigned" ] },
    vehicleObject: 1,
    count: 1
  }
}, { $sort: { count: -1 } }, { $limit: 10 });
```

To explain the above:
The Mongodb aggregate framework is the way forward for complex queries like this. Firstly, I run a $match to filter the records. Then, we use $lookup to grab the vehicle record. Worth mentioning here that this is a Many to One relationship here (lots of stats, each having a single vehicle). I can then group on the vehicle_id field, which will enable me to return one record per vehicle with a count of the number of stats in the group. As it is a group, we technically have lots of copies of that same vehicle document now in each group, so I then add just the first one into the vehicleObject variable. This would be fine, but $first tends to return an array with a single entry (pointless in my opinion), so I added the $unwind stage to pull the actual vehicle out. I then added a $project stage to calculate an additional field, sorted by the count descending and limited the results to 10.

And take a breath :)

I hope that helps someone. If you know of a better way to do what I did, then I'm open to suggestions to improve.